# API's not accessible from DigitalOcean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-services, digital-ocean

I have API's in my project. ON localhost and heroku it works fine. I deployed it on digitalcoean. It works fine from browser and postman and even mobile browser. But when I access in my android app it gives an error

> You've requested an IP address that is part of the CloudFlare network. A valid Host header must be supplied to reach the desired website.

Comment: Are you making the request manually? If so, add a "Host: [domain here]"-header, as it seems that CloudFlare needs it. Web browsers automatically send this header.